# Reduce the size of generated image files from canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have create a meme generator. The problem with it is that the image I get from canvas have large size. Typical size is 600KB. Is it normal? Can I do something to reduce the image size? I would post the code but I don't think the code matters.

Comment: Are you using canvas.toDataURL()? You can not do anything about that. But you can use some library to encode PNG / JPG with smaller size.

Comment: Yes, I am using Canvas.toDataURL(). Could you please link to some libraries.

Comment: Google Chrome used to have horrible PNG compression ratio, I reported it as a bug and it improved. Try this one https://github.com/devongovett/png.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reduce the URL size by specifying that `toDataURL` encode using jpg instead png.

```
var jpgURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

You can also specify an image quality to further reduce the URL size.

```
var jpgURLat50PercentQuality = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
```

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hey markE, Thank you. The size is down from 600KB to 27 KB.